# How to handle special characters in a wget download link?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I have a link like this:

```
 wget --user=user_nm --http-password=pass123 https://site.domain.com/Folder/Folder/page.php?link=/Folder/Folder/Csv.Stock.php\&namefile=STOCK.Stock.csv
```

But while the password authorization is fine, `wget` still cannot process the link. Why?

Answer (score 10):

The safest way when handling a link from e.g. a browser is to use single quotes (`'`) to quote the whole link string. That way the shell will not try to break it up, without you having to manually escape each special character:

```
wget --user=user_nm --http-password=pass123 'https://site.domain.com/Folder/Folder/page.php?link=/Folder/Folder/Csv.Stock.php&namefile=STOCK.Stock.csv'
```

Or, for a real example:

```
wget --user-agent=firefox 'https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+shell+singl+quote&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mageia:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=bash+single+quote&rls=org.mageia:en-US:official'
```

Keep in mind that server-side restrictions might make using `wget` like this quite hard. Google, for example, forbids certain user agent strings, hence the `--user-agent` option above. Other servers use cookies to maintain session information and simply feeding a link to `wget` will not work. YMMV.